# prime numbers switch in a java program has unexpected output

Tags: java, for-loop, switch-statement

I'm trying to create a program that reads a list of 10 integers and asks the user whether they'd like to know if the integers entered are even/odd, prime, or their sign.
I don't see where the mistake is:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Menu1 {
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
    BufferedReader b=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int array[]=new int[10];
    int a=0, i=0;
    System.out.println("Welcome, please enter 10 integers:");
    try{
        for(i=0;i<10;i++){
            System.out.println("Enter integer "+(i+1)+":");
            array[i]=Integer.parseInt(b.readLine());
        }
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        System.err.println("Not an integer! "+e.getMessage());
    }           
    System.out.println("What would you like to know?\n(1) Even/Odd\n(2) Primes\n(3) Sign");
    try{
        a=Integer.parseInt(b.readLine());   
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        System.err.println("Not an integer! "+e.getMessage());
    }       
    switch (a){
    case 1:
        for(i=0;i<10;i++){
            if(array[i]%2==0)
                System.out.println(array[i]+" is even");
            else
                System.out.println(array[i]+" is odd");
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
            for(i=2;i<array[j];i++){
                if(array[j]%i==0)
                    System.out.println(array[j]+" isn't prime");
                else
                    System.out.println(array[j]+" is prime");
            }
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        for(i=0;i<10;i++){
            if(array[i]>0)
                System.out.println(array[i]+" is positive");
            else if(array[i]<0)
                System.out.println(array[i]+" is negative");
            else
                System.out.println(array[i]+" has no sign");
        }
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid Option");
    }
}
```

}

case 1 and case 3 work just fine, case 2 is where the strange output occurs; any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: What sort of "strange output" are you getting?

Comment: Define "strange output"

Comment: You need to decide whether the number is prime before printing it.  For now each number you check you'll print N-2 times, where N is the value in the array.  Adjust your 2nd for loop to stop when "isn't prime" is determined, then only print once.

Comment: here is the output using eclipse luna:What would you like to know?
(1) Even/Odd
(2) Primes
(3) Sign
2
5 is prime
5 is prime
5 is prime
7 is prime
7 is prime
7 is prime
7 is prime
7 is prime
9 is prime
9 isn't prime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a function to check if a number is prime or not:

```
public static boolean isPrimeNumber(int number) {
    if (number == 2 || number == 3) {
        return true;
    }
    if (number % 2 == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    int sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(number) + 1;
    for (int i = 3; i < sqrt; i += 2) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can call this function for every number you want to check.

Your case2 would be like:

```
 case 2:
    for(int j=0;j<10;j++){    
            if(!isPrimeNumber(array[j]))
                System.out.println(array[j]+" isn't prime");
            else
                System.out.println(array[j]+" is prime");
    }
    break;
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code for case 2:

```
case 2:
    for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
        for(i=2;i<array[j];i++){
            if(array[j]%i==0)
                System.out.println(array[j]+" isn't prime");
            else
                System.out.println(array[j]+" is prime");
        }
    }
    break;
```

you have put a `System.out.println()` statement that will execute for every iteration of the for loop. So, if a given element in your array, `array`, is 5, your code will print out whether or not your number is divisible by every number from 2 to 5. This probably isn't what you want.

To fix this, there are a few options: for one, you could have a boolean flag that you set when you discover that the number isn't prime, and then check that and print your results after the inner for loop:

```
case 2:
    for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
        boolean isPrime = true; // assume it's prime
        for(i=2;i<array[j];i++){
            if(array[j]%i==0)
                isPrime = false;
                break; // get out of the inner for loop early
        }
        if(isPrime)
            System.out.println(array[j]+" is prime");
        else
            System.out.println(array[j]+" isn't prime");
    }
    break;
```

Comment: The code at the end is the wrong way round. It needs `isPrime` to default to `true`, and then get set to `false` if a divisor is found. The `println` statements are also inverted.

Comment: Ah, you've corrected the first problem. The `println` statements are still the wrong way round, though.

Answer (score 0):

For a programming exercise, the answers given will do just fine. If this were a real application, using very large numbers, the algorithm that checks every possible divisor (or even the slight improvements on this) would be very slow.

Although it's possible to test for primality with certainty much more efficiently than this, in practice it's very, very efficient to check that a (very) large number is *almost 
certainly* prime. This is what gets used in cryptographic applications.

For further details, you could look up [Miller-Rabin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test).

If you want an implementation you can use off-the-shelf, then convert your number to a `BigInteger` and then use `BigInteger.isProbablePrime(int certainty)` to determine whether it's probably prime. You can make the "probably" very close to certainty and it'll still be extremely efficient.